# Laravel getting wrong relationship result after save relationship

Tags: laravel

in my web application i have two tables as `users` and `paymants` with this models:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $guarded = [
        'id'
    ];

    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Payment::class);
    }
}

class Payments extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'payments';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

each user has many payment records and each payments belongs to one user, now i create simple payment record with finding user

```
$user = User::find(2);

$user->payments()->create(
    [
        'resnumber' => 'dwwe',
        'price' => '1111',
        'invoice_id' =>'asdasd',
        'month_key' => 'k8Cv2YfuO4jOLXd',
        'month_id' => 6,
        'payment' => false
    ]
);
```

this code work fine and that can create successful payment record, now i want to get this saved record with relation ship for example:

```
$data = $user::with(['payments'])->first();
```

result is empty:

```
  #relations: array:2 [▼
    "payments" => Collection {#367 ▼
      #items: []
    }
```

full testing code:

```
Route::get('/testPayment', function () {
    $user = User::find(2);

    $user->payments()->create(
        [
            'resnumber' => 'dwwe',
            'price' => '1111',
            'invoice_id' =>'asdasd',
            'month_key' => 'k8Cv2YfuO4jOLXd',
            'month_id' => 6,
            'payment' => false
        ]
    );

    $data = $user::with(['payments'])->first();
    dd($data);
});
```

migration code:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('month_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('month_id')->references('id')->on('months')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('month_key');
        $table->string('resnumber');
        $table->string('invoice_id');
        $table->string('price');
        $table->boolean('payment')->default(false);
        $table->string('card_holder')->nullable();
        $table->string('result_code')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and now there is **BIG PROBLEM**

after change user_id value in mysql database for example from `2` to `1` i have this result :|

```
  #relations: array:2 [▼
    "payments" => Collection {#378 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => Payment {#375 ▶}
      ]
```

this payment record is not for user which id is `2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new User query which is returning the wrong User.

```php
$user = User::find(2);

$user->payments()->create(
    [
        'resnumber' => 'dwwe',
        'price' => '1111',
        'invoice_id' =>'asdasd',
        'month_key' => 'k8Cv2YfuO4jOLXd',
        'month_id' => 6,
        'payment' => false
    ]
);

$data = $user::with(['payments'])->first();
dd($data);
```

1. You find the `User` with an id of `2`
2. You create a payment for `User#2`
3. You query for every `User` eager loading `payments` and then return the first

This is happening because `$user` is both a `User` *and* the `User` model. `$user::with` *does not* say "get payments for this $user" it says "get all `User` with their payments" -- it's equivalent to `User::with('payments')->first();`

You already have the `User` you're interested in so your code should look like this:

```php
$user = User::find(2);

$user->payments()->create(
    [
        'resnumber' => 'dwwe',
        'price' => '1111',
        'invoice_id' =>'asdasd',
        'month_key' => 'k8Cv2YfuO4jOLXd',
        'month_id' => 6,
        'payment' => false
    ]
);

dd($user->payments);
```

Comment: so, how about multi relationship? for exmple: `$data = $user::with(['payments', 'months' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('id', 'asc');
    $query->with('lessons')->latest();
}])->first();`

Comment: You should use `with` when you're querying for the first time, once you have a Model you can access the relationships directly by using `$user->relationship` which Laravel will either return the loaded data or load it and then return it.

Comment: If you want to query multiple items for the first time then use `User` do not use `$user` as it makes your code unclear and causes this confusion.

Comment: so can i use single query to get all? or i have to use separator query to get them?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean, do you want to get all users or all payments?

Comment: Sorry, can you please answer either "I want to get all Users with their payments" or "I want to get all payments for the User that I just created a payment for".

Comment: I want to get all payments for the User that I just created a payment for

Comment: `$payments = $user->payments` will return all payments for that user, if you want to do additional scoping you can do `$payments = $user->payments()->orderBy('id', 'asc');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190213/discussion-between-doldurma-and-sam).